# Combine (not merge) audio files in Audacity with time gap

Tags: audio, audacity

I would like to combine few audio files to one long audio file.

I was able to align them by `Select All> Tracks> Align Tracks> Align End to End` and then combine by `Tracks> Mix and Render`. But I would like to insert one second silence in-between, which I do not know how to do.

Kindly suggest

Attaching an image of what I managed to do.

[image]

Comment: Hi, pkj. Welcome to [so]! This question is not related to programming, and I would suggest deleting it. If you still have the question, it may be on-topic at https://sound.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only a few files, then the easiest way is:

- Launch Audacity
- "File menu > Import > Audio" and select the files
- Zoom out a bit so that you can see some space beyond the end of the tracks
  (See: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/zooming.html)
- Use the Time Shift Tool to arrange the tracks as shown below
  (See https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/time_shift_tool.html)
  "File menu > Export" and select whichever options you need.